# Automatic discover of Python subpackages in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have the following project structure:

```
project_dir
├── my_package
│   ├── subpackage
│   │   ├── bar.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── not_wanted_package
│   ├── other.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

I want to create Python package containing `my_package` (and all its subpackages), **but not** `not_wanted_package`. Using `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`.

The following `setup.py` works fine:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
        name='my_package',
        version='1.0',
        packages=['my_package', 'my_package.subpackage']
)
```

But when I will add/remove/rename any subpackage I will have to manually update this file. I can use functions provided by `setuptools`, but `find_packages()` discovers all packages (including `not_wanted_package`). On the other hand `find_packages('my_package')` discovers only `subpackage`.

Is there any way to use `find_packages()` or `find_namespace_packages()` to automatically discover `my_package` **and** its subpackages?

Answer (score 1):

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    …
    packages=find_packages(include=['my_package']),
    …
)
```

When keyword `include` is used in `find_packages` only such packages are included. Every other packages including `not_wanted_package` are not listed.

Or you can exclude it with `exclude=['not_wanted_package']`

Answer (score 0):

`find_packages` supports excluding packages according to the [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages). If that is insufficient you can still simply use `find_packages` but filter the output against a static list of excluded packages. `setup.py` is a standard Python file which means that adding your own code to it is not a problem.

```
from setuptools import find_packages

def filter_packages(...):
    ...

setup(
    ...
    packages=filter_packages(find_packages("src")),
    ...
)
```

If your problem lies only in discovering all packages and not only subpackages then see what the file structure used by `werkzeug` looks like. The way that repository is organised aims to eliminate problems with `find_packages`. As you can see the `werkzeug` directory in the repository is placed in an extra `src` directory effectively making it `src/werkzeug`.

https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/c6dfc4880328fe9c4558d2b2e2325761f4e17f58/setup.py#L51